# Como passar um valor de um coluna da tabela para um formulário em outra página PHP via HTTP?

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de passar o valor de `exibir_colunas['cd_cliente']` da página **Listar clientes** pela tag `<a>` (lembrando que o `#atu_cli` serve de ancora para o formulário pois é um id do formulário de atualização).

```
echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'."<a href='/web/form_crud/form_update_cliente.php/#atu_cli'> Atualizar </a>".'</td>';
```

E na página de formulário **Atualizar cliente** o valor de `exibir_colunas['cd_cliente']` ser recebido pelo campo `<select>` pelo `value="<?php echo $exibir_colunas['cd_cliente']; ?>`.

```
<?php

        // Mostrar todos os erros do php
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'] = $_GET['cd_cliente'];

        try {

            $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente ORDER BY cd_cliente");
            $resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();

        } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
            echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
            die;
        } catch (Exception $falha) {
            echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
            die;
        }
    ?>
 
<p> ID cliente:
    <select onclick="buscaDados()" name="cd_cliente" id="cd_cliente" value="<?php echo $exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'] ?>">
            <option value=""> Nenhum </option>
            <?php foreach($resultado_selecao as $valor): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $valor['cd_cliente'] ?>"><?= $valor['nome'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Introdução

Certo, sobre a sua dúvida é importante entender alguns conceitos para entender como os dados são trafegados via HTTP. O HTTP possui alguns métodos, entre eles os mais famosos e mais comuns são o GET e o POST.

- O GET é normalmente usado para obter dados, você usa ele quando clica
  em um link em um site ou quando digita um endereço na barra do
  navegador.
- O POST é normalmente usado para enviar dados, você usa ele ao
  submeter formulários por exemplo.

Outro conceito do HTTP é o de Requisição e Resposta. Uma requisição é o ato de solicitar ou enviar algo ao servidor, enquanto uma resposta é o que o servidor lhe devolve. Elas podem ou não ter um corpo, mas sempre terão um cabeçalho, que é a parte que fala se deu sucesso ou não.

O que você menciona de querer enviar uma informação pelo href pode ser entendido como enviar uma informação pela Query String.

Ao enviar uma requisição você pode adicionar a URL o caracter ?, ex.

```
http://exemplo.com?parametro1=valor1&parametro2=valor2
```

Neste exemplo na nossa URL se ela for usada como link ao clicar o que ocorre é:

- Uma requisição GET é enviada para http://exemplo.com
- Na query string são enviados 2 parametros (parametro1 e parametro2).

Assumindo que você esteja usando PHP você iria pegar estes valores usando a variável mágica $_GET.

Para isso você teria um código como:

```php
<?php

$valor1 = $_GET['parametro1'];
$valor2 = $_GET['parametro2'];
```

## Aplicando ao seu caso

No seu caso o que você faria seria algo como

#### Listagem

```php
<a href='/web/form_crud/form_update_cliente.php/?cd_cliente=<?= $exibir_colunas['cd_cliente']; ?>#atu_cli'> Atualizar </a>
```

#### Página de atualização

```php
<?php
//... seu código, em algum momento inicializa $exibir_colunas como array.
$exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'] = $_GET['cd_cliente'];
//... mais código
?>
<p> ID cliente: <select onclick="buscaDados()" name="cd_cliente" id="cd_cliente" required="" value="<?php echo $exibir_colunas['cd_cliente']; ?>"> </p>
```

## Considerações.

Espero que isso tenha auxiliado a entender como essa passagem ocorre pelo PHP e tenha resolvido sua dúvida.

Comment: Ainda não consegui.

Comment: Acho que é no formulário de atualização, pois na de listagem está correto.